# WebSockets and HTTP security with shared Session and user Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, security, websocket

So I'm looking into making a graphic chat application/website (users sit around in a room in 2D avatars and chat) and from all the research I've done so far (a lot!), a LAMP stack will seem to suit me for most of the site, with some node.js and websocket protocol used for handling the actual chat data sent (user messages, etc). I'm not extremely experienced with creating anything of this scope (I'm more accustomed to front-end work), but so far it's a fun challenge!

My problem is, I can't seem to find a lot of information about verifying user information. I've read that websockets are inherently fairly unsecure and it's good to verify the source of the data being sent...

My concern, though, is the actual identity of the user. If I use Javascript to initiate the socket connection, how do I prevent the user from "spoofing" any information? Is it possible to hook up a user's PHP session data to the server handling the websocket connections so the Javascript wouldn't be handling anything but the actual message text?

For example, if I logged in as "Kris" and sent the message "Hello!" or changed my avatar's image, I'd only want client side to handle the "Hello" or the avatar image URL, and keep all of the other information being passed back and forth such as username on the server side in order to prevent anyone from messing with the client-side code.

Answer (score 5):

The question is to broad and do not touch any specific challenge except lack of knowledge and experience.

While I will still comment on some points that might be useful for you:

1. WebSockets security is same as HTTP requests security - it is up to your application.
2. Sticky sessions are required to identify and persist session from different processes/servers. If you decide to use LAMP (which I would recommend not to) then you do indeed need sticky session between PHP and node.js process.
3. WebSockets during connection (handshaking) does normal HTTP request with some extra and normal cookies data. That can be used on server-side to restore session and relate client socket to that session. Once socket is disconnected it will have to loose that relation.
4. Restoring session using HTTP request or WebSockets is pretty much identical in terms of security, as WebSockets actually come after session is restored.
5. Multiple tech stack, might lead to complexity with proxying node.js through Apache to work from same domain. For application you've described, I do not see need of this old-school + modern stack mixture. You can go purely node.js with nginx in front for serving static files. That will be much easier to work with as well your code language will be more persistent across project, and makes it easier to maintain.
6. RESTful is much easier to create using node.js so it again will save time. Actual logic behind RESTful API can be reused directly by your node.js to get data for socket.io if you want as well.
7. You need server<>client authoritative politics in terms of communication. Client only "asks" and servers does the decisions based on what it thinks is right or wrong. And that should be a rule #1 in terms of security. If client will make decisions that will allow others to hack and cheat.

Again - this is too broad, and very "discussion" style question rather than a specific challenge.

Comment: Good answer. You should not that support for HTTP authentication (e.g. HTTP Basic) is limited in modern browsers. Means you need to implement some authentication logic on top of your web socket layer.

Comment: I use to avoid any authentication on WebSockets, and doing it before on HTTP, using some OAuth or similar techniques, once it is done - session user is created, and only then once WebSockets making connection, you restore session and check if you are authenticated - if no, disconnect, if yes - great, you are secure.

Comment: Clever workaround! I personally try to avoid state server side but good idea :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is a "workaround" :), it is the "right" way of doing things. WebSockets are not independent thing, they needs to be on top of normal HTTP as always.
You in fact could do similar stuff like OAuth but over WebSockets as well.

Comment: Depends on if you want to built an app stateless (which I consider a good practice) in this case you cannot easily use the upgrade handshake because of incomplete HTTP support